# How to Get Data From Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, qualtrics

Hey I am creating a webapplication that process answers from a Qualtrics survey that I created. Is there a way (such as AJAX request) that automatically get the answers from my Qualtrics form through javascript? Thanks!

Comment: https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/docs.php This is the REST api documentation, you would need the api enabled on your account though.

Comment: What kind of account type can generate API token? I am using individual and I cannot do it...

Comment: It is an add-on feature you should give your rep a call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualtrics provides a REST API: http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/api-integration/qualtrics-rest-api/

You would use the API command getLegacyResponseData to get response data. You can use AJAX to call the API.